# Modify Date/Time from SQLDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a date column in my database, it's not date time so the values have no time attached.

However, when I drag and drop a *SQLDataSource* on my page and bind a `dropdownlist` to it to display the date, it automatically adds a time of `12:00:00 AM`.

I know why it does this, but I don't know how to get rid of it. Do I need to bind it from codebehind?

Is there an easy fix to this?

Comment: I think you can still a format to it in the generated code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set DropDownList.DataTextFormatString.

```
<asp:DropDownList
id="datesList"
runat="server"
dataTextFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"/>
```

Then after DataBinding your control will apply the correct format:

Answer (score 1):

Add format to field or column definition. For example Gridview:

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="Your_Date_Column" dataformatstring="{0:MMMM d, yyyy}" htmlencode="false" />
```

BTW, other method is to use ViewModel - class which is needed only for displaying data. In this class there is no need to use DateTime or other data types: only string. For example, you can define some displaying defaults here: if value null, show text "UNDEFINED" or what you need. In some cases this approach makes centralized point where you make preparation of data for display.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show your sql query it may be useful .Have you use convert(varchar,date ,103) method to your query

Comment: there is no time in the database so I haven't used convert in my sql statement, it's a .net runtime issue.

Answer (score 0):

C# doesn't have date datatype and though values from sql(date) datatype is convert to datetime field in c#. So better convert date as nvarchar in sql using convert(varchar,date ,103) though C# treats it as string.